# How can I dismiss a pushViewController in iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I need to make a button to dismiss the child view controller from a pushViewController. The action is exactly like the left (back) button on the top navigation bar.

How can I dismiss a `pushViewController`? Which method should I use ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `popViewControllerAnimated:` method should do it.

Comment: Digging this one back up just to say thankyou from the distant future of 2013 :)

Answer (score 7):

In my case where [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAllContacts" sender:self]; pushes a new ViewController, in order to close(dismiss) that view controller which has been pushed I use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This is called for a custom button which I added to the navigation bar!